Nest - next авторизация
Делаю вручную стандартную авторизацию на Next - Nest js. Настраиваю refresh token в куках через сервер, ну база. Локально работает все правильно. Но когда деплою, клиент серверных кук не видит. Я пробовал сделать прокси - сервер как api маршрут на Nextjs. Типо чтобы все запросы были серверными. Но это не помогло. Кто нибудь сталкивался с этим? Я не сильно шарю за Docker или nginx, извините, если вопрос глупый
